# Finding the indices of first negative elements in a 3-d matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider the matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `fxmxm`, e.g. with `f=4` and `m=3`

```
A(:,:,1)=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12]

A(:,:,2)=[0.5 2 -1; 3 -1 0; 7 -5 8; 10 11 12]

A(:,:,3)=[-2 2 -2; 2 -2 -1; 7 -5 -3; 10 -2 0]
```

The characteristic of `A` is the following: consider the vector `1xm` `[A(i,j,1) A(i,j,2) ... A(i,j,m)]`. We have that `A(i,j,1)>=A(i,j,2)>=...>=A(i,j,m)`. This holds for any `i,j` with `i=1,...,f` and `j=1,...,m`.

Without using loops, I want to construct the matrix `B` of dimension `fxm` such that `B(i,j)` gives the index of the first negative element in `[A(i,j,1) A(i,j,2) ... A(i,j,m)]`. If there are no negative elements in `[A(i,j,1) A(i,j,2) ... A(i,j,m)]`, `B(i,j)` should be equal to `m+1`.

In the example above

```
B=[3 4 2; 4 2 3; 4 2 3; 4 3 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this using a combination of [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).

We can determine the row, column and slice locations for each of the values that are negative with `find` and `ind2sub`, take the row and column locations which will act as groups and will serve as our input key into `accumarray` and use the slice locations that are negative as the value associated with each key.  For each of the unique row and column locations, we determine the slice number that was negative that is the smallest.  The result will be a matrix where each location will tell you the first slice that was negative.

However, for those 3D columns that aren't negative, what `accumarray` will do is set these locations to 0.  With the resulting matrix, any values that are 0, set them to `m+1`:

```
ind = find(A < 0);
[rows, cols, slices] = ind2sub(size(A), ind);
B = accumarray([rows cols], slices, [size(A,1), size(A,2)], @min);
B(B == 0) = size(A,3) + 1;
```

For your example, we get:

```
B =

     3     4     2
     4     2     3
     4     2     3
     4     3     4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the two-output form of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to act as “`find` along a given dimension”, as follows:

```
[v, B] = max(A<0, [], 3);
B(~v) = size(A,3)+1;
```